# git submodule unpushed commit update

Tags: git, git-submodules

so my git project has a submodule, and i make a change and commit it, **but i don't push** , then on the parent i issue command

```
git submodule update
```

which reverts the submodule , but where did the commit go, can i get it back?

normally if i had pushed the sub module commit it would have gone to the server, and then i would always be able to run the following command and it pulls it back down from the server.

```
git submodule update --remote
```

Comment: `cd submodule_dir` and then `git reflog` could be useful to find the commit.

Comment: go to the submodule and `git checkout @{1}`